# Mongodb aggregation query inside an array over multiple entries

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have a mongo DB which looks like this -->

collection name : users

```
{ username:'something'
  _id : ObjectId(someID1)
  acl : { users : [ObjectId(someID1),ObjectId(someID2),ObjectId(someID3)] , group : [grpID4,grpID5,grpID6] }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I want to have an aggregation query which looks in all documents for db.users.acl.users and finds a count of each unique objectID.

It is like adding all arrays of users.acl.users and then returning the count of each unique ID in a python dictionary

```
{
"result" : [
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("someID1"),
                "count" : 20                 

        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("someID2"),
                "count" : 2
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectID("someID3")
                "count" : 1
        },

],
"ok" : 1
}
```

I have tried the pythonic way, that first adding all the arrays and then finding the count, but i want to do it more by query as compared to more by python. I pretty clueless how to query inside an array such as this.

any idea where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when working with arrays in MongoDB in the aggregation framework you want to use the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline operator to "de-normalize" the contents as separate documents. The allows you to work with them in other pipeline stages:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$acl.users" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$acl.users",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Python syntax is generally basically identical to the shell syntax of JavaScript, so direct examples such as [SQL to Aggregation mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) should generally apply.